# Unattended installation of OS for laptops

Tags: windows-10, xml, unattended, xml-schema-validation, autounattend

I am able to install the Windows 10 OS by creating an unattended.xml file containing basic settings like region, hostname, partition etc.
But I need to include more settings for example; renaming the administrator and guest accounts, setting passwords for them, joining system into domain, Enabling remote connection, installation of applications etc.
Can anyone help me in achieving this?
I need to know how to get the result readily available after installation of OS completes.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: As you have a domain, couldn't you deploy most of those settings through domain GPOs? We have a GPO that enables RDP and configures the firewall rules.

Comment: Use the [sysprep](https://www.techtarget.com/searchenterprisedesktop/definition/Sysprep-System-Preparation-Tool) tool provided by Microsoft.

Comment: Thankyou @SeñorCMasMas Can you tell me how to include renaming accounts, setting passwords in the same unattended.xml file itself?